# JPA Entities not scanned during unit test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, junit

I have a mature java application using Hibernate/JPA that is working just fine.  We are trying to add some unit/integration tests.  I am doing this using Spring's TestContext framework, my test class is like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class ServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void testWorkspaceThing() throws Exception {

        List<MyEntity> entities = myService.someMethod();
        assertNotNull(entities);
    }
}
```

I copied/pasted all the necessary context configuration from the application context into ServiceTest-context.xml.  This includes context:component-scan, defining the dataSource, entityManagerFactory beans, etc.  When the application is running, I have no errors.  When running this test, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: MyEntity is not mapped.
```

For any and all Entity classes I try to query.  The Entity classes are annotated with javax.persistence.Entity, etc.

Does anyone know why this would fail using TestContext?

**Update**

Our persistence.xml file is essentially empty:

```
<persistence-unit name="some-pu" />
```

So I assume it's auto-scanning to find all the annotated Entity classes.  Could be a difference in the directory structure between how it's deployed in tomcat vs. the folder structure while running the unit test?  Our persistence.xml is in WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF

Also - I noticed you can define "packagesToScan" with Spring 3.1 but we are using Spring 3.0.6.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by running the junit test via ant.  I copied the persistence.xml file to build/classes/META-INF so that it would be in the same folder tree as the compiled entity classes and this allowed scanning to work and the test to run correctly.

This works in Eclipse if I delete the Webcontent/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF copy of persistence.xml and leave it in the build/ folder.  I wonder if there's a better way to make it work in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

This message usually says that you've not mapped your entities in hibernate.cfg or persistence.xml

```
<mapping class="com.yourpackage.MyEntity" />
...other entities
```

Make sure that `MyEntity` class is mapped in there and its annotation in the class is exactly `@Entity(name="MyEntity")`

**EDIT**: If you're using Spring 3.1 above, try instructing the EntityManager factory bean in your test context with:

```
  <property name="packagesToScan">
     <list>
        <value>com.yourpackage.domain</value>
     </list>
  </property>
```

Comment: See my update above, persistence.xml is pretty bare.  Deployed inside tomcat this works just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately we're using 3.0.6.  I wonder if there's any way to fix this without upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your persistence.xml file.

```
<persistence-unit name="some-pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<class>package.MyEntity</class>

        <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="USER-DB"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="PASSWORD-DB"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://SERVER-IP/some-pu?autoReconnect=true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>

         <!-- Determines how many connections at a time c3p0 will try to acquire when the pool is exhausted. :: default=1 -->
        <property name="connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="2"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1"/> 
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="10"/> 
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>     

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: I appreciate the help but I would like to have it auto-scan - we have a large number of entities.

Comment: You try to specify your spring context? on the line @ContextConfiguration you need to add: ({Spring-context}). So the result is `@ContextConfiguration({Spring-context})`