# How to have JPA with Hibernate provider auto-scan for entity classes

Tags: hibernate, jpa, gradle, intellij-idea, junit

there's a LOT of questions on this on the internets.. however I still struggle with what seems to be a quite typical scenario.

I'm doing a quite simple JPA (using Hibernate) project, with Entity classes being resided with a `com.actions.domain` package

I have `persistence.xml` as follows:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="my-persistence-unit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                      value="org.h2.Driver" />

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:h2:~/test.h2db" />

            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

this file resides in `src\test\resources\META-INF` folder

I have also JUnit test classes written like this:

```
protected EntityManager entityManager;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("my-persistence-unit");
    entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}

@Test
public void actionsAdded_success() {
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(new Action("TEST_ACTION1", "ACTION"));
    entityManager.persist(new Action("TEST_ACTION2", "ACTION"));
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

An example of an Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UC_ACTIONS")
@Data
public class Action {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String type;

    public Action(String name, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

If I put a `<class>com.actions.domain.Action</class>` element into persistence unit description, it all works like a charm, however I don't want to enumerate the classes here by hand, also don't want to have any `hibernate.cfg.xml` file

So if I remove that element, and try to somehow have provider auto-scan for entities, I get errors like `Unknown entity: com.actions.domain.Action`

I've tried running these tests both a Run configuration in IntelliJ and as a `gradle test` command. In none of the cases META-INF folder is in the same directory as `classes`, so how are people achieving this ??

How on Earth can one have it working ?

UPDATE: there's an accepted answer to identical question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16598682/2583044 Still, I'm struggling to believe that such a main-stream use case issue could have such a marginal dirty hack of a solution :(

Comment: `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>`

Comment: When you ask question , write which build tool you use.

Comment: "and as a gradle test command." .. apprently I had to be more specific at that moment, hard to expect that the replying person will read the whole question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved (thanks to [Vlad Mihalcea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1025118/vlad-mihalcea)) ultimately as follows:

1. Moved the `META-INF` folder under `src/main`
2. Added the following to `build.gradle`:

   apply plugin: 'idea'

   idea {
       module {
           inheritOutputDirs = true
       }
   }

   sourceSets {
       main {
           output.resourcesDir = "build/classes"
       }
       test {
           output.resourcesDir = "build/classes"
       }
   }

Afterwards, tests are working as expected both from IDEA and with Gradle.

Answer (score 2):

By default autodetection works for entities in the same classpath item as persistence.xml. It can be configured by  elements.

To enable correct autodetection when persistence.xml is in src/test/resources/META-INF I use the following trick:

***persistence.xml***

```
<persistence ...>
      <persistence-unit ...>
            <jar-file>${project.build.outputDirectory}</jar-file>
            ...
      </persistence-unit>
  </persistence>
```

***pom.xml - enable resource filtering for src/test/resources:***

```
<project ...>
    ...
    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: huh.. the trick is I use Gradle.. but thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: Your suggestion is on point, but unfortunately it uses Maven so formally I cannot accept it ((